# AWS Lambda Versioning - How do I have two separate lambda alias in a production stage?

Tags: version-control, aws-lambda, versioning

I have a mobile app that invokes an AWS Lambda say for e.g. 'Hello'. Let's assume that there is a change to the 'hello' lambda function and it's published to a new version 2. But this lambda function will be invoked by the mobile App version 2 and will be available to users who have updated the App.

For users who haven't updated the mobile App, the lambda invocation must still be  made to the previous version.

This is very similar to API versioning which is usually achieved by adding a '/v1/' etc. to the API signature to denote the version of the API currently available publicly.

How do I have two versions of the same lambda existing to support backward compatibility? Is it by having them point to 2 different aliases?

For folks who need a refresher on Lambda versioning and alias, here it is -

- Lambda versions are like git commits— they’re snapshots of your project history. Each version has a number that serves as its ID, starting with 1 and incrementing up.
- Note that you can only publish a version if you’re on the special version called “$LATEST”. This is the default version that all Lambda functions start on. This version $LATEST acts similar to git’s staging area — you make your changes there and when you publish a version, it takes whatever is in $LATEST and saves it as the new version — just like a git commit.
- Aliases are simply pointers to versions. As a metaphor, think of how you might have a pointer to different servers for development, staging, or production.
- Once a new version is published, you can attach an alias to a version which will be referenced by the client code.

Comment: We have solved this problem and the detailed account of the same is mentioned in the blog over here [https://blog.talentica.com/2018/03/08/aws-lambda-automated-deployment/]

Comment: that link is broken - please add your solution as an answer to this question inline, without using external links

Answer (score 1):

You can use the version number to access the previous versions of your Lambda code.

Say you have versions 1,2,3,4.. of your Lambda function "**Hello**".  Access the revision(or commit) '3' using,

```
Hello:3
```

Like that you can access the latest version using,

```
Hello:$LATEST
```

Or simply by the function name itself

```
Hello
```